# Jasmine JQuery testing won't recognize p tag as hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I'm trying to use Jasmine and Jasmine-JQuery to test some code I'm working on.  However, I wrote a simple test to see if a `click` listener is being triggered.  I followed a tutorial showing how to set up spies and to use those to see if events were triggered.  While that works fine, when I added the jasmine-jquery matcher `toBeHidden()` it keeps returning false.  I've tested the method out by clicking on the button that triggers the event and by selecting it and calling `click()` on it.  I've also tried putting it in a `setTimeOut` callback to make sure the event was triggered, but it doesn't work either.

Here's my listener

```
$("#b1").click(function(){
    $("#p1").hide();
});
```

Here's my test

```
describe("Hide, Show, Toggle Tests", function() {
  var spyEvent;
  function setUpToggleFixture() {
    setFixtures('<div class="container">'
            + '<button id="b1">Hide Paragraph</button> <button id="b2">Show Paragraph</button> <button id="b3">Toggle Paragraph</button>'
            + '<p id="p1">Lorem</p></div>');    
  }

  beforeEach(function() {
    setUpToggleFixture();
  });

  it ("should invoke the hide click event.", function() {
    spyEvent = spyOnEvent('#b1', 'click');
    $('#b1').click());

    expect('click').toHaveBeenTriggeredOn('#b1');
    expect(spyEvent).toHaveBeenTriggered();
    expect($("#p1")).toBeHidden();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has any difficulty with testing JQuery with Jasmine keep in mind that by wrapping any code in a `$(document).ready(function(){ });` it will prevent it from being testable by Jasmine. My solution was to wrap my selector in a JS function expression and call that function in the `$(document).ready(function(){ });` like so,

```
//my js file
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  hide();
});

function hide(){
  $("#b1").click(function(){
    $("#p1").hide();
  });
}
```

And test it like so

```
beforeEach(function() {
  setFixtures('<div class="container">'
            + '<button id="b1">Hide Paragraph</button> <button id="b2">Show Paragraph</button> <button id="b3">Toggle Paragraph</button>'
            + '<p id="p1">Lorem</p></div>');
});

it ("should hide the paragraph.", function() {
  hide();   //I need to call the method before running it now that I wrapped my 
           //method in a function expression
  $('#b1').click();

  expect($("#p1")).toBeHidden();
});
```